# Do the activities of my LLC need to be limited to a particular field?

Tags: united-states, small-business, limited-liability-company

I started an LLC for my small business making and selling picture frames, but have since also started work on a couple of self-published books. Is there any reason I can't consider both ventures to be part of the same LLC?

Comment: No.  There are no restrictions which limit the range of activities undertaken by an LLC.  See http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/llc.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. When you file your Articles of Organization, simply state that your business will operate under the law. You don't need to give any further specification.

Comment: Should just note that you'll need a better answer for banks, just when they ask